# Can't create List<Node> object when list contains one element

Tags: java, rest-assured

I'm using rest-assured 2.8.0 library in my Java tests. When I create an xmlPath from the rest-assured String response and the try to create a List of Nodes I get an exception if the List contains only one element.

```
List<Node> nodeList = xmlPath.getList("commentary.messages.period.message", Node.class);
```

This should give me a List with exactly one element but instead I get an Exception

```
Cannot convert class java.lang.String to interface com.jayway.restassured.path.xml.element.Node. java.lang.ClassCastException at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408) at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:80) at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105) at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60) at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235) at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:247) at com.jayway.restassured.internal.path.ObjectConverter.convertObjectTo(ObjectConverter.groovy:54) at com.jayway.restassured.path.xml.XmlPath.convertObjectTo(XmlPath.java:913) at com.jayway.restassured.path.xml.XmlPath.getAsList(XmlPath.java:879) at com.jayway.restassured.path.xml.XmlPath.getList(XmlPath.java:348) at com.performgroup.usbasketballbackend.sprint26.USBask382Test.checkPlayerMainEventWithQualifierMessagesComments(USBask382Test.java:125)
```

When I have 2 elements I do not get this exception. Please help :)

Below is the xml structure and if there is one message node it doesn't create a list with one element.

```
<commentary xmlns:basketballdata="www.nba.com">
  <matchInfo>
    <description>Oklahoma City Thunder vs Houston Rockets</description>
    <sport id="456">basketball</sport>
    <competition id="1" name="NBA">
    <country id="123" name="USA"/>
    </competition>
  </matchInfo>
  <messages>
    <period id="1">
      <message id="123" homeScore="0" awayScore="0"/>
    </period>
  </messages>
</commentary>
```

But if I have 2 message nodes it creates a list with 2 elements.

```
<commentary xmlns:basketballdata="www.nba.com">
  <matchInfo>
    <description>Oklahoma City Thunder vs Houston Rockets</description>
    <sport id="456">basketball</sport>
    <competition id="1" name="NBA">
    <country id="123" name="USA"/>
    </competition>
  </matchInfo>
  <messages>
    <period id="1">
      <message id="123" homeScore="0" awayScore="0"/>
      <message id="456" homeScore="2" awayScore="0"/>
    </period>
  </messages>
</commentary>
```

Comment: Can you show the data samples that cause the exception and the one that doesn't?

Comment: I've added a sample xml. I hope that helps.

Comment: I think that is bug/feature, one element - not list, two or more - list. Catch class cast exception and get as single element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because of very odd behavior of Groovy to Java conversion in in `xml-path-2.8.0-sources.jar!/com/jayway/restassured/assertion/XMLAssertion.groovy`

Look what's happening:

```
private def toJavaObject(nodes, isAttributes, forceList) {
    if (nodes.size() == 1 && !hasChildren(nodes, isAttributes)) {
        return nodes.text()
    } else {
        return toJavaList(nodes, isAttributes, forceList)
    }
}
```

If a list of nodes consists of exactly one element with no children, this element has no rights to be a node according to this implementation. It's converted to a `String`. This triggers a `ClassCastException` in your code later on, as you're expecting a `Node` and getting a `String`.

So getting a list of nodes seems to be broken. You can't use it. You have to find a workaround that suites your test scenario. For example, you can access attributes as a list of strings:

```
List<String> nodeList = xmlPath.getList("commentary.messages.period.message.@id", String.class);
```

Comment: Thank you @nolexa, the workaround works for me. The intention of my tests was to verify the attributes anyway. Unfortunately the bug remains relevant since List<Node> can't be created with one element.